# Bootstrap Table animation on TR doesnt work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap table and actually I want to remove a row. But if I do this, it doesnt look smooth to simply remove it so I thought... hey just use an animated `.hide()`:

```
$('.myTR').hide('slow', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

this actually has the same result. The row gets hide slowly and the next bottom row just pops up.

Next try was to animate the hight of the row:

```
$('.myTR').animate({
   height: "0px"
}, 1500 );
```

Doesnt work... Actually it works... but only if I make it bigger...

Is there a Trick to do that ?

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk816g96/)

In this fiddle you have to click the row to expand it and than you can see the rows of an other table with the glyphicon-trash icon. Clicking on the Icon turn hight into 0px.

**Edit:**

[More try's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk816g96/2/)

here I tried to give the row a `display` attribute... and I have a reaction but it still looks freaky ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me some time but now I know how to do the trick.

Here is the solution for all who looking for this...

*(The trick is animating all containing td's)*

```
$('.myTR').children('td').animate({
    'font-size': 0,   //needed
    opacity:0,        //optional but looks smoother
    height:0,         //needed
    padding:0         //needed
},function(){
    $('.myTR').remove();
});
```

In my script I have an icon in a TD. If I click on it I want the table-row to get hide smoothly. So I get the above `tr` like `.closest('tr')`. But simply animate the `tr` height doesnt work since there are some elements in the `tr` with some css settings. e.g. `font-size` or `padding`.

So to solve this, selecting all `td` in the `tr` is needed (`.children('td')`). Than the `.animate()` works as expacted. See sample above or [this FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qk816g96/7/)

Answer (score 1):

One posibility is to remove effectively the row, but at the same time transform the rows under it inthe Y direction, so that they don't move.

You need to know the row height before hand

If this transform is set inside an animation, then you set it to 0 afert the time that you consider

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qk816g96/1/)

```
$('.glyphicon-trash').on('click', function(){
    $(".test").removeClass('test');
    $(this).closest("tr").nextAll().addClass('test');
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});

.test {
    -webkit-animation: move 1s;
    animation: move 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {transform: translateY(23px);}
  100% {transform: translateY(0px);}
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {transform: translateY(23px);}
  100% {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

Notice that for this to work a second time, the test class should be removed in a timeout after the animation has happened. The method that I used in the fiddle won't work reliably

Comment: since I use pnotify and the nice events "after_open" or/and "after_close" (there are a lot more) I could handle it like this. But it still looks a bit dirty when it gets removed...

Comment: i found our that setting the row to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` lets the effect go on a bit... but its not doing all....

Comment: It looks dirty because I didn't adjust the height. See https://jsfiddle.net/qk816g96/3/

Comment: This works very nice, only the last row wont animate